# How do I get a list of unique random integers? Avoiding numbers being drawn twice

Tags: random

I am trying to get a set of random integers for which I used the function `RandomInteger[{1, 50}, 5]`. That way, however, there is the chance to get doubles such as `{46, 7, 9, 39, 39}`. How do I avoid numbers being drawn twice?

Thank you very much for your help

Sincerely

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are searching is the function [`RandomSample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomSample.html)

```
RandomSample[Range[50], 5]
```